# Docker mysql:5.6 exits with code 141 if I mount a volume

Tags: mysql, docker

I have been doing volume mounting with this image for weeks now without an issue. Suddenly now, if I try to mount a volume, *ANY* volume, the container prints some basic startup logs and exits.

The app itself give no indication of error so this appear to be docker itself squashing things.

This is what I have:

Docker Version (native on mac):

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

local directory:

```
$ ls
1                  Dockerfile         README.md          Schema             dba_utilities      docker-compose.yml docs
```

Fireup a MYSQL container:

```
$ docker run -d  -v $PWD/Schema:/root:ro -v $PWD/dba_utilities:/tmp:ro -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  mysql:5.6
aa213c8cb28ea2f75e3064b296db6e5e450466cc45e60a7de3f21a2ca98987f4
```

Now prove it's dead:

```
$ docker ps -a | head -3
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS               NAMES
aa213c8cb28e        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   23 seconds ago      Exited (141) 21 seconds ago                          inspiring_curie
cc43d27b29cf        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   4 minutes ago       Exited (141) 4 minutes ago                           laughing_shaw
```

Now show container logs:

```
$ docker logs aa213c8cb28ea2f75e3064b296db6e5e450466cc45e60a7de3f21a2ca98987f4
Initializing database
2017-10-02 18:31:00 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-02 18:31:00 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2017-10-02 18:31:00 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 36 ...
```

But, if I try to bring up a shell from that same image with those same volumes all looks good:

```
$ docker run -it  -v $PWD/Schema:/root:ro -v $PWD/dba_utilities:/tmp:ro -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  mysql:5.6 /bin/bash
root@898fe2f883a2:/# cd
root@898fe2f883a2:~# ls
README.md  db1  db2
root@898fe2f883a2:~# ls /tmp
README.md  apply.sh  dump_all.sh  pullschema.sh  schemata.txt
root@898fe2f883a2:~# pwd
/root
root@898fe2f883a2:~# exit
```

Now, if I remove the volume mounts:

```
$ docker run -d   -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  mysql:5.6 
98b51f96fe482cfd0453a0eb4ff8b9d1f2729244ad2316e245680ce4976a200d
```

and check the status:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
98b51f96fe48        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        3306/tcp            nervous_mcnulty
```

It's running. Verifying from logs:

```
docker logs 98b51f96fe482cfd0453a0eb4ff8b9d1f2729244ad2316e245680ce4976a200d
Initializing database
2017-10-02 18:36:48 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-02 18:36:48 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2017-10-02 18:36:48 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 36 ...


2017-10-02 18:36:53 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-02 18:36:53 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
2017-10-02 18:36:53 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 59 ...
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
2017-10-02 18:36:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-02 18:36:56 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 87 ...
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2017-10-02 18:36:59 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-10-02 18:36:59 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.37) starting as process 1 ...
```

In the past, even when there is an issue with the volume mounts it either errors immediately or I get no mount but not this.

I have also tried this on an **ubuntu 14.04 VM** with the **same results**

Comment: 141 is `SIGPIPE`, so perhaps your OS is killing it as part of the service startup.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is to remove the read-only flag from mount and the env variable addressing, it worked for me and I was able to reproduce your error on `Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737` so it looks like a wider issue, I tried omitting both env variable usage and :ro flag and none worked, only not using both worked here

```
docker run -d -v Schema:/root -v dba_utils:/tmp -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql:5.6
```